# Collatz/Hailstone Sequence in Java - Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: java

I have the following code below which I have put together quickly to find the number with the largest [Hailstone sequence](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10008.5.shtml), between 1 and 99999. The program works fine up to 35655, generating a hailstone count of 324. Anybody familiar with the challenge will know that the largest sequence is generated by 77031 (giving 354). You can see from my `println()` statement(s) output that for some reason the `if statement` just stops evaluating once it gets past 33655. The other `println()` statement validate that my `generateSequence()` method appears to be working fine. Any ideas as to what is going wrong here?

Code below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Hailstone {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hailstone hs = new Hailstone();
}

public Hailstone () {

    System.out.println("Size of sequence for 35655 is: " + generateSequence(35655).size());
    System.out.println("Size of sequence for 77031 is: " + generateSequence(77031).size());
    calcLargestSeqLength(100000);             
}

/**
 * 
 * finds the number with the largest hailstone sequence between 1 and aNum
 */
private void calcLargestSeqLength(int aNum) {

    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < aNum; i++)
    {         
        int size = generateSequence(i).size();
        if(size > largest)
        {
            System.out.println("if statement evaluated to true for: " + i + " / " + size);
            largest = i;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number with the largest sequence is: " + largest);
}

private ArrayList<Integer> generateSequence(int aNum) {

    ArrayList<Integer> hSeq = new ArrayList();

    int x = aNum;
    hSeq.add(x);

    if (x != 1)
    {
        while (x !=  1)
        {
            if ((x % 2) == 0)
            {   
                x = x/2;
                hSeq.add(x);
            }
            else
            {
                x = (3 * x) + 1;
                hSeq.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
    return hSeq;
}
```

}

Output from NetBeans:

```
Size of sequence for 35655 is: 324
Size of sequence for 77031 is: 351
if statement evaluated to true for: 1
if statement evaluated to true for: 2
if statement evaluated to true for: 3
if statement evaluated to true for: 5
if statement evaluated to true for: 6
if statement evaluated to true for: 7
if statement evaluated to true for: 9
if statement evaluated to true for: 11
if statement evaluated to true for: 14
if statement evaluated to true for: 15
if statement evaluated to true for: 18
if statement evaluated to true for: 19
if statement evaluated to true for: 25
if statement evaluated to true for: 27
if statement evaluated to true for: 31
if statement evaluated to true for: 39
if statement evaluated to true for: 41
if statement evaluated to true for: 47
if statement evaluated to true for: 54
if statement evaluated to true for: 55
if statement evaluated to true for: 62
if statement evaluated to true for: 63
if statement evaluated to true for: 71
if statement evaluated to true for: 73
if statement evaluated to true for: 82
if statement evaluated to true for: 83
if statement evaluated to true for: 91
if statement evaluated to true for: 94
if statement evaluated to true for: 95
if statement evaluated to true for: 97
if statement evaluated to true for: 107
if statement evaluated to true for: 108
if statement evaluated to true for: 109
if statement evaluated to true for: 110
if statement evaluated to true for: 129
if statement evaluated to true for: 313
if statement evaluated to true for: 35655
Number with the largest sequence is: 35655
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Number 1: Are you sure it isn't just taking a really, really long time to run?  Number 2: Are you sure it isn't overflowing?

Comment: Following ajb's suggestion, did you try using `long` instead of `int` ?

Comment: It runs in seconds ajb, and as shown from the output, the number is being calculated. As to overflowing, i'm not getting any exceptions thrown by netbeans. Program terminates sucessfully. I've previously put an additional Println in the for loop to make sure it executes right up to 99999, so that isn't the problem. Definitely something to do with the if statement...

Comment: OK, I see the problem.  How are you computing `largest`?

Comment: @Dici I don't think that can be the problem as the largest number anywhere in the program is 100000, well within the bounds for an int.

Comment: @ajb largest is just a holder for the current biggest sequence. size is calculated using the ArrayList.size() method once the full sequence has been generated.

Comment: No, the point is to look at your code for how you're computing `largest`.  It's not correct.

Comment: @Dave0504 besides what ajb pointed out, I would like to make you realise than 100000 may be the largest number used as the *first* element of the sequence, but nothing ensures you the sequence itself will contain larger numbers. Proof is that the second number of the sequence starting with 100000 is 200000, which is larger. I'm not saying it can actually overflow, I don't know how this sequence behaves, but this is not *impossible* until proved

Comment: Completely agree with Dici. Literally nobody on the planet understands the Collatz problem, so you can't assume `int` is big enough. This should really be done with `BigInteger`, or overflows checked for.

Comment: @Dici Once I had completed the generateSequence() method I completey forget about the actual calculations that were happening! I see what you mean know about not knowing how big the numbers in the calculation could get, possibly causing it to overflow. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks for all your help Paul. I think the issue mentioned in the other comments in your answer about the initial inputs overtaking the record lengths, made me miss the flaw in the logic. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dici just had another thought prompted by your suggestion to use long. If the calculations were exceeding the bounds of int as suggested, i'm presuming that the number would wrap around from max bound to min bound, meaning that it was very very unlikely that the if statement would ever evaluate to true again.

Comment: If it wraps and becomes negative your program could get stuck forever. e.g. `-2` goes to `-1` which goes back to `-2` etc etc

Comment: @Dave0504 `3*Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` yields `2147483646`, so it can be positive after an overflow. However, it might not be possible that `3 x + 1` overflows to an integer greater than `x`. I don't know, that's why I would use `long` since it costs me nothing

Comment: @Dici thanks, have now reimplemented using long. Will be something to remember to check in future. A you pointed out, if it costs nothing, no reason not to use long.

Comment: @Dave0504 it takes more space in memory but you are not storing a lot of them If you had large collections of integer it would be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `largest` to mean the largest size and also to mean the value generating the largest size.

You need two variables: `largest` and `startingValueForLargest`.

```
largest = i;
```

should be

```
largest = size;
startingValueForLargest = i;
```

What's happening at the moment is that `largest` is being set to 35655 so 354 is not beating it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the program now works, however can you explain why it was working fine up until 35665, and not afterwards?

Comment: Because that's the point that the size of the initial imputs start overtaking the record lengths they generate.

Comment: @Dave0504 Actually, you have no basis for saying "it was working fine".  The logic was supposed to compute the largest size and tell you what number generated the longest sequence.  It displayed the wrong answer.  Nothing about that part of the logic "worked fine".